# Flex mobile facebook clear the session after logout

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, mobile, logout

I'm trying to build Facebook Flex mobile app for Android And iOS,
I tried to connect Facebook using `Facebook Mobile.login(call Back);`

when I tried to do `Facebook Mobile.log Out();`

I don't know if it logs me out or not,
but I think I'm not clearing the session so it is not showing me Facebook login window anymore.

Any help on this? how to clear session?
and how to get back to the Facebook login window?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: Yes FacebookMobile.Logout method is there to achieve this.